# Each div in a container more opacity than previous div

Tags: jquery, css, arrays, rgba

I'd like to create a row of divs that each have a background color with a bit more opacity than the previous. Creating a sort of gradient.

[image: http://imgur.com/AoAXtti]

To generate a different opacity for each div, I created a variable that uses the ID of said div. But this has not resulted into anything useful. Taking on too much without knowing all the basics, sadly.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("div").each(function(index, value) { 

        var ids = $(this).attr('id');
        var opa = ids/10

        $("div").css("background-color", "rgba(255, 255, 255, "+opa+")");

    });

});
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Are you making the id of the element a number?

Comment: Looks like you're applying each to every div. Try setting your background color on `$(this)` instead.

Comment: Yes @ BuddhistBeast. And thanks, Chad!

Comment: @eskimoproverb you might want to change the approach of how you calculate the opacity, because by dividing by 10, you limit yourself to 10 divs before it hits max opacity of 1, and every div after that will be the same color (because the opacity is maxed out). Consider using the method I stated in my answer below, in which you can have as many divs as you want, and the gradient will be even from the first div being totally white, and the last being totally black.

Comment: Another Way http://jsfiddle.net/qd9zyxxw/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there! The `$("div")` when assigning the background-color should be `$(this)` as you don't want to set it on all elements but only on the current one.

```js
$(function(){

    $("div").each(function(index, value) { 
        var ids = $(this).attr('id');
        var opa = ids/10;
      
        $(this).css("background-color", "rgba(255,255,255, "+opa+")");
    });

});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #000;
}

.box {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>

<div class="box" id="1"></div>
<div class="box" id="2"></div>
<div class="box" id="3"></div>
<div class="box" id="4"></div>
```

Comment: I was a lot closer than I thought I was. Ha! Thanks everyone. En vooral jij, ckuijjer!

Comment: Hehe :) Graag gedaan!

Answer (score 0):

The main thing is that with `$('div').css('background-color'...`, you're setting the background color of all of the `<div>`s by looping through them again. Try changing that to:

`$(this).css('background-color', 'rgba(255, 255, 255, ' + opa + ')' );`

That way, the `$.each` function will get the ID and assign the computed value to the current `<div>` in the loop. I think that sounds like what you're looking for.

Also, technically speaking, ID values must start with a letter (upper- or lower-case). A `data` attribute might be a better place to put the value you need. For example:

```
<div data-opacity="1">
```

Which can be accessed using jQuery like this:

```
$([element selector]).attr('data-opacity')
```

OR

```
$([element selector]).data('opacity')
```

Example: http://codepen.io/a_double/pen/NPRrYG

Answer (score 0):

Perhpas another approach is to not use indexes or values, but the div element itself because by using ids, you limit yourself to the physical number of divs you put with ids.  here's what i'm talking about:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('div').css('background-color', 'black');

    var numDiv = 0;
    var totalDiv = 0;
    $("div").each(function(){
        totalDiv ++;
    });
    $("div").each(function() { 
        var opa = numDiv/totalDiv;
        var colorrgba = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, ' + opa + ')';
        $(this).css("opacity", opa);
        numDiv++;
    });
});
```

With the above code, we see that you can add as many divs, and it will take the that specific div order in terms of the total number of divs to define the opacity of each div (so you'll have a consistent gradient).

See the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swm53ran/1/)

Comment: Hi! Thanks for offering a better alternative. :)

Answer (score 0):

A couple things first, you were applying your css to all divs instead of the current div the loop was pointed to. You then want to divide the 100% opacity value (1) by the total number of divs you have on the screen. Then every iteration add the divided amount to the running total and apply that as an opacity value.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var length =  1 /  $("div").length,
        opaTot = length,
        opa = length; //Complete opacity is 1

    $("div").each(function(index, value) { 

        var ids = $(this).attr('id');
        $(this).css("background-color", "rgba(255, 255, 255, "+opaTot +")");
        opaTot += opa;

    });

});
```

Here is a fiddle to test my example.
http://jsfiddle.net/v5bd5byf/1/

Answer (score 0):

Actually this can be easily achieved with pure Javascript, http://jsfiddle.net/4p6vtz46/:

```
var opa=0.3;
var divs = document.getElementsByClassName('opacity');

for (i=0; i<divs.length; i++) {



    (function () {

        divs[i].style.opacity = opa;
        opa+=0.3;
    })();

}
```